# About using supress blank field in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am developing software with c# and I create crystal report that get data from datagridview and show it 
the problem is that I have three field in datatable but when field is empty it lefts empty space. I want to fit the field to other when empty, like this:

[image: desired outcome]

and when show up in report like this

[image: real outcome]

I want to supress the blank field and my report designer

[image: designer]

thank you so much for reading and answering ..

this is how look my report designer .
[image]
and i have two diffrent type of report look like this 
[image]
and the other .
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put you ExParameter into separate section (you can have multiple sections from same logical part of report) and use suppress condition for entire section (or just check 'suppress blank section' in section expert).

In addition, you should group by Analyse and put Analyse value into group header - this way you won't duplicate this part of report either.

Comment: Hey but i need exparameter in details because in some reports it have value .... And in other do not have value .... Thanks

Comment: how could you explain

Answer (score 0):

Right click on this field, click on **Format Field**, click on **Common** tab and then Check the **Suppress If Duplicate**
[image: this way]

Comment: Hey thanks for answer but this window dialog do not appear in section 3 details .... And in page header it appear but do not do anything ...thanks again